# Submit the form inside jquery dialog box without reloading page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have php page with a form, I want to open it in a dialog box and submit and show the data on same dialog without reloading the page

## php

```
            <form accept-charset="UTF-8">

            <button type="submit" class="addButtonClass"></button>
```

please advice

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.addButtonClass').submit(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
    ....
    .. Now your usual ajax post        
    }
```

Comment: I want to show the results on same form. Ex: when user submit values im returning the current data list from database to this json_obj['usergroup'] , how can I show those data after submission on dialog box?

Comment: In your success function add the results to the DOM. `success` in the success callback will be an object and you can modify the DOM with jquery and show the desired result.

Comment: page is still reloading when click on submit :/

Answer (score 0):

Modify this

```
$('#add_user1').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //** prevent normal form submission and page reload

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: $link,
        data: $('#add_user1').serializeArray(),
        success: function (data) {
            var json_obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            var result = json_obj['result'];
            var usergroup = json_obj['usergroup'];
            var success = json_obj['success'];
            var errorAry = {
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I want to show the results on same form. Ex: when user submit values im returning the current data list from database  to this json_obj['usergroup'] , how can I show those data after submission on dialog box?